# Dynamic API requests from user input

Tags: javascript

i'm new to API's and am building a webpage that calls an API and gets some data to build a table and display it. Currently the page runs the buildTable() function on page load and takes a URL value. Here is the entire page code:

```
function buildTable(url) {
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(serverList => {
    let table = document.querySelector('#mainTable');
    table.innerHTML = '';
    table.innerHTML = '<tr><th>Server Name</th><th>Rank</th><th>Players</th><th>Last Wipe</th><th>Country</th></tr>';

    for (let item in serverList.data) {
        console.log(serverList.data[item]);
        let row = document.createElement('tr');

        let serverName = document.createElement('td');
        serverName.innerHTML = `${serverList.data[item].attributes.name}`;

        let serverRank = document.createElement('td');
        serverRank.innerHTML = `${serverList.data[item].attributes.rank}`;

        let serverPlayers = document.createElement('td');
        serverPlayers.innerHTML = `${serverList.data[item].attributes.players}/${serverList.data[item].attributes.maxPlayers}`;

        let serverWipe = document.createElement('td');
        let currentTime = new Date();
        let wipeTimeString = `${serverList.data[item].attributes.details.rust_last_wipe}`;
        let wipeTime = new Date(wipeTimeString);
        let daysWiped = (currentTime.getDate() - wipeTime.getDate());
        let wipeMessage = `${daysWiped} Days ago`;
        serverWipe.innerHTML = `${wipeMessage}`;

        let serverCountry = document.createElement('td');
        serverCountry.innerHTML = `${serverList.data[item].attributes.country}`;

        row.appendChild(serverName);
        row.appendChild(serverRank);
        row.appendChild(serverPlayers);
        row.appendChild(serverWipe);
        row.appendChild(serverCountry);

        table.appendChild(row);

    }
})
```

}

```
buildTable(`https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers?page[size]=100&filter[game]=rust`);
```

To filter/sort data from the API I only need to change the existing URL by adding parameters on the end. Example:

```
`https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers?page[size]=100&filter[game]=rust&filter[search]=large`
```

My question is how do I take user input to change the URL and load the new data? I tried using a form with text inputs and call the buildTable() function with the new URL, but it just refreshes the page and the default buildTable() data displays. I also tried preventdefault() with the form but it didn't work.

Comment: You definitely have to call `preventDefault()` on the submission event or the page will refresh. The main task here is to insert the input values into the URL, which is just a string. That is the code we need to see, not the pretty much irrelevant and working buildTable function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how do I take user input to change the URL and load the new data?

If you use an `URL` object, you can conveniently set the individual query parameters.

Here is an example assuming an input box `#filterInput`:

```js
const filterInput = document.querySelector('#filterInput')

const url = new URL('https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers?page[size]=100&filter[game]=rust')
url.searchParams.set('filter[search]', filterInput.value)

buildTable(url)
```

> I tried using a form with text inputs [...] but it just refreshes the page

If you do use a form for the user input, you have to call `preventDefault` in the submission event as well. Note that it's with capital `D` (unlike what you wrote in your question) and you need to call it on the event object that gets passed as first argument into your event listener:

```js
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  // code from above here
})
```